# what is the error "Unexpected IRQ trap at 00"?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am registering an irq at 0 for my board in `3.18.y` rpi kernel using device tree then i didnt get any error like `"Unexpected IRQ trap at 00"`, but when i moved to `3.19.y` rpi kernel doing the same giving the above error.

What excatly it means?

I studied the patches between the 3.18.y and 3.19.y and found alot of changes. Maximum  of them are   `to support hierarchy irqdomains`

I am unable to know why I am getting this error now.
Its continueing after booting also, all my dmesg is filling with that error only.

Why I am getting this error?

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: What device is listed in device 00 ?
You can see with 'cat /proc/interrupts  | grep ^00:'

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Its my device only